# Confused about ViewHolder pattern and convertView

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am new to Android development and reading through some example code.  I have copied one method from the sample code in an Adapter class (derived from ArrayAdapter), the derived class has a checkbox in addition to the text view:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  View listItem = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

  CheckedTextView checkMark = null;
  ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) listItem.getTag();
  if (holder != null) {
    checkMark = holder.checkMark;
  } else {
    checkMark = (CheckedTextView) listItem.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    holder = new ViewHolder(checkMark);
    listItem.setTag(holder);
  }

  checkMark.setChecked(isInCollection(position));
  return listItem;
}

private class ViewHolder {
  protected final CheckedTextView checkMark;

  public ViewHolder(CheckedTextView checkMark) {
     this.checkMark = checkMark;
  }
}
```

The sample code is to optimize the getView by caching the View within a ViewHolder object.

Where I am confused is I thought the convertView, if not null, would be re-purposed and then the View data is populated into it and returned.

If this is the case, then how could the setTag / getTag methods called in the code be relied upon? It would seem that the same object would have to be retrieved in order for it to work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you not sure what `convertView` is and how it is provided to `getView()`? Are you confused as to how items in the adapter are tagged?  Or are you unsure of how holding a view works?

Comment: setTag is called to cache data, and later getTag is called on subsequent calls to get it back.  I don't see how we can be guaranteed to have the same object, i.e. perhaps view returned from getTag on a subsequent call is for a different list item, and returns the wrong view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> perhaps view returned from getTag on a subsequent call is for a different list item, and returns the wrong view

Adapters use a RecycleBin. This class allows the ListView to only create as many row layouts as will fit on the screen, plus one or two for scrolling and pre-loading. So if you have a ListView with 1000 rows and a screen that only displays 7 rows, odds are the ListViiew will only have 8 unique Views.

Now to your question using my example above: only eight row layouts and 8 subsequent ViewHolders are ever created. When the users scrolls *no new* row layouts are ever created; only the *content* of the row layout changes. So `getTag()` will always have a valid ViewHolder that references the appropriate View(s).

(Does that help?)

Comment: I think I understand it, but it seems that the solution is relying on the Adapter RecycleBin implementation details - specifically that the RecycleBin would respect the order of the rows that are visible?  When I read about adapters, I had assumed it could randomly get any object available from its pool

Comment: The RecycleBin doesn't interact with the visible rows and the RecycleBin's scrap pile should only hold one layout (unless you are using multiple row layouts.) However the Adapter should keep the visible layouts ordered. In other words once a layout is assigned content, this particular row shouldn't receive new content until visiting the scrap pile and then being recycled.

Answer (score 5):

You're on the right track, here's some information that may help make more sense of how ListViews work:

A simple implementation of the `getView()` method has two goals.  The first is inflating the View to be shown on the list.  The second is populating the View with the data that needs to be shown.

As you stated, ListViews re-purpose the Views that compose the list.  This is sometimes referred to as view recycling.  The reason for this is scalability.  Consider a ListView that contains the data of 1000 items.  Views can take up a lot of space, and it would not be feasible to inflate 1000 Views and keep them all in memory as this could lead to performance hits or the dreaded `OutOfMemoryException`.  In order to keep ListViews lightweight, Android uses the `getView()` method to marry Views with the underlying data.  When the user scrolls up and down the list, any Views that move off the screen are placed in a pool of views to be reused.  The `convertView` parameter of `getView()` comes from this list.  Initially, this pool is empty, so null Views are passed to `getView()`.  Thus, the first part of getView should be checking to see if `convertView` has been previously inflated.  Additionally, you'll want to configure the attributes of `convertView` that will be common to all list items.  That code will look something like this:

```
if(convertView == null)
{
    convertView = new TextView(context);
    convertView.setTextSize(28);
    convertView.setTextColor(R.color.black);  
}
```

The second part of an implementation of `getView()` looks at your underlying data source for the list and configures this specific instance of the View.  For example, in our test list, we may have an Array of Strings to set the text of the view, and want to set the tag as the current position in the Data of this View. We know which item in the list we're working with based on the `position` parmeter.  This configuration comes next.

```
String listText = myListStringsArray[position];
((TextView)convertView).setText(listText);
convertView.setTag(position);
```

This allows us to minimize the amount of time we spend inflating/creating new views, a costly operation, while still being able to quickly configuring each view for display.  Putting it all together, your method will look like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup)
{ 
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = new TextView(context);
        //For more complex views, you may want to inflate this view from a layout file using a LayoutInflator, but I'm going to keep this example simple.

        //And now, configure your View, for example...
        convertView.setTextSize(28);
        convertView.setTextColor(R.color.black);  
    }

    //Configure the View for the item at 'position'
    String listText = myListStringsArray[position];
    ((TextView)convertView).setText(listText);
    convertView.setTag(position);

    //Finally, we'll return the view to be added to the list.

    return convertView;

}
```

As you can see, a ViewHolder isn't needed because the OS handles it for you!  The Views themselves should be considered temporary objects and any information they need to hold onto should be managed with your underlying data.

One further caveat, the OS does nothing to the Views that get placed in the pool, they're as-is, including any data they've been populated with or changes made to them.  A well-implemented `getView()` method will ensure that the underlying data keeps track of any changes in the state of views.  For example, if you change text color of your TextView to red onClick, when that view is recycled the text color will remain red. Text color, in this case, should be linked to some underlying data and set outside of the `if(convertView == null)` conditional each time `getView()` is called.  (Basically, static setup common for all convertViews happens inside the conditional, dynamic setup based on the current list item and user input happens after) Hope this helps!

Edited - Made the example simpler and cleaned up the code, thanks Sam!

Comment: +1 for including some good details. But `convertView.setText(listText);` won't compile as is since `convertView` is declared as a View (not a TextView) and you never use `getTag()` so I'm not certain why you use `setTag()`.